# Converting PPT file to PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, powerpoint

I have a macro which opens a PowerPoint file stored on the workbook and then modifies it using the below code

```
Set PApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PApp.Visible = True
Pth = ThisWorkbook.Path
ErrorPopUp = True

Dim TsyTemplate As Object

Set TsyTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report    Templates").OLEObjects(“Report 1”)
TsyTemplate.Copy
Sheets("Version Control").Paste
Set TsyTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Book 1").OLEObjects(1)
TsyTemplate.Verb Verb:=xlOpen

Set TsyTemplate = Nothing

Set PPres = PApp.ActivePresentation
```

This works fine however I want to add some code which then converts the open PowerPoint file into a PDF file. I would prefer it to just convert it without saving it somewhere but I don't believe this is possible so I am using he below code to save it as a PDF FILE

```
PDFName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/test.pdf"
PPres.ExportAsFixedFormat Path:=PDFName,     FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF,     RangeType:=ppPrintSelection
```

This isn't working though as I get the error message "type mismatch"

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Full code:

```
Global PApp As Object
Global PPres As Object
Global PPTFileName As String
Global ppFixedFormatTypePDF As Long
Global ppPrintSelection As Long
```

Sub Test_Printing_To_PDF()

```
Set PApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PApp.Visible = True
Pth = ThisWorkbook.Path
ErrorPopUp = True

Dim TsyTemplate As Object

Set TsyTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report Templates").OLEObjects("Report 1")
TsyTemplate.Copy
Sheets("Version Control").Paste

Set TsyTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Version Control").OLEObjects(1)

TsyTemplate.Verb Verb:=xlOpen

Set TsyTemplate = Nothing

Set PPres = PApp.ActivePresentation


PPres.Slides(1).Shapes("Presentation_Title").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test printing code"


ppFixedFormatTypePDF = 2
ppPrintSelection = 2


PDFName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/test.pdf"
PPres.ExportAsFixedFormat Path:=PDFName, FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, RangeType:=ppPrintSelection
```

End Sub

Comment: Where do you DIM your variables and what have you DIMmed PPres as?  Alsol ppFixedFormatTypePDF and ppPrintSelection are PPT constants, not defined in Excel, so you'll need to define them (both as Longs = 2)

Comment: Hi Steve. Variables are defined eleaewhere in the module. Ppres is defined as object. I hadn't defined the other 2 so have done that (as longs and = 2) but I still get the type mismatch message

Comment: What line does the error occur on?  FWIW, The PDF export portion of your code works as expected within PowerPoint with just a few mods to suit the fact that I ran it within PPT.  But you're setting PPres to the active presentation but IS there an active presentation?  You haven't opened one or added any slides to the default presentation, so what exactly are you trying to export as PDF?

Comment: Error occurs on the ppres.exportasfixedformat. I've added the full code into the main body to simplify

Comment: Please answer the other questions in previous comment; thanks.

Comment: Yes there is an active presentation and I amend slide 1 on it before I try and save it as a PDF the code opens up the presentation stored in the document amends the first slide and then tries to save it as a PDF. The code is breaking at the ppres.exportasfixedformat line

Comment: OK, so next try changing it to RangeType:=ppPrintAll  (and add "CONST ppPrintAll as Long = 1" (sans quotes) at top of the module. Does that affect the error any?

Comment: Still the same error message on that same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed some of your Excel code so that I could try this here; since it seems to have nothing to do with the PDF export from PPT, shouldn't make any difference.  New (working) code below with comments:

```
Option Explicit

Global PApp As Object
Global PPres As Object
Global PPTFileName As String
Global ppFixedFormatTypePDF As Long
Global ppPrintSelection As Long

Const ppSaveAsPDF As Long = 32

Sub Test_Printing_To_PDF()

' Always include Option Explicit and DIM all variables
Dim Pth As String
Dim ErrorPopUp As Boolean
Dim PDFName As String

Set PApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PApp.Visible = True
Pth = ThisWorkbook.Path
ErrorPopUp = True

' Just invoking PowerPoint doesn't necessarily create a presentation.
' You need to add one (or open an existing one)
Set PPres = PApp.presentations.Add

' And creating a new presentation doesn't necessarily add slides so:
PPres.slides.Add 1, 1

' Unless you've opened a presentation that happens to have a shape named
' Presentation_Title on the first slide, this will fail:
'PPres.slides(1).Shapes("Presentation_Title").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test printing code"
' So I've changed it to this:
PPres.slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test printing code"

' / isn't a valid character:
'PDFName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/test.pdf"
' so I changed it to this:
PDFName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.pdf"

' And there are all sorts of reports all over the net about
' the Export routine being buggy.  Substitute this and it works:
PPres.SaveAs PDFName, ppSaveAsPDF


End Sub
```